# Scala string interpolation and evaluate expression

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

I am diving into Scala's string interpolation feature and I wonder if it is safe to use it. String interpolation allows us to evaluate expression like:

```
println(s"Hello World! ${for (i <- 1 to 100) println(s"other values $i")}")
```

My doubt is if we should evaluate expression in interpolated string. I see a lot of Scala code where other developers are using this feature like in example and don't know if this is correct and safe.

Comment: This syntactically correct but looks very ugly. Are you sure you would use this code in production and happy to maintain this?? this is  safe to use.

Comment: I don't want to see code like this on production. But I cannot explain other developers why they should not do this.

Comment: Are you asking if some actual scala code could be in this evaluation? code generation etc? In this case I would assume there could be a problem if evaluation fails, to complex questions. Not sure if practical though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would never use it and I would not want my colleagues to use it.

Two things are essentially off:

- String interpolation is a nice feature because it makes concatenation of values easy to read... unless you stick an entire scala program in there :)
- Not only there's a complex expression in there, but you're using a side-effect, so in the process of evaluating the interpolation 100 values will be printed. So you get

  ```
  other values 1
  other values 2
  ...
  other values 100
  Hello World! ()
  ```

Where the `()` is the return value of the for-comprehension, i.e. `Unit`.

I would save myself (and my colleagues) tremendous headaches and just do

```
println(s"Hello World!")
for (i <- 1 to 100) {
  println(s"other values $i")
}
```

Comment: Is string interpolation performing equally to plain old string concatenation?

Comment: String concatenation is slighly faster, so if that's your bottleneck, use it instead of interpolation. The difference is negligible in most use cases, but - as always - decide according to your requirements. See http://yosoyu.com/index.php/2015/03/14/string-interpolation-vs-string-concatenation/